# How to get the list of users based on a reputation threshold?

Tags: stackexchange, dataexplorer

I tried to take a list of users with reputation greater than 5 using a Stack Exchange explorer simple query:

```
select id
from users
where reputation > 5
```

I get only 50,000 rows. I expected to get millions. Is there any threshold? Is there any way to get them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cross-site duplicate of ["Why can't I pull in all the SO users from Data Explorer?" on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213050/why-cant-i-pull-in-all-the-so-users-from-data-explorer).

The Data Explorer (SEDE) limits to 50K rows.

Either refine your query or download and use [the Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) instead.  That's what the Data Dump is for.

Alternatively, you can [access the Data Dump via Google's *BigQuery*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow) -- which also has an API.